# How to pass a string from Class 1 to Class 2 to Class 3?

Tags: c#, string, class

I have 3 classes (UCourse, Student and Teacher) and each class has a unique `string` property.

Is there a simple way I can take the `string` property from the first class `UCourse`, pass it into a 2nd class `Student`, and then pass that string plus another string from the 2nd class into a 3rd class `Teacher`?

This is what I have so far for my 3 classes:

```
using System;

namespace EDXonline_AssignmentFour
{
    class Program
    {
        class UCourse
        {
            // Set the unique string for the 1st class
            private string course = "Computer Scienece";
            public string Course
            {
                get { return course; }
            }
        }

        class Student
        {
            // Get the string from the 1st class
            UCourse ucourse = new UCourse();
            public string coursef1
            {
                get { return ucourse.Course; }
            }

            // Set the unique string for the 2nd class
            private string name = "zach";
            public string Name
            {
                get { return name; }
            }
        }

        class Teacher
        {
            Student student = new Student();

            private string namet = "Sally";

            // Get the unique string from the 2nd class
            public string namef1
            {
                get { return student.Name; }
            }

            // Set the unique string for the 3rd class
            public string Namet
            {
                get { return namet; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I need to create an instance of `Teacher` and by using only this instance of `Teacher`, I need to output all `string` properties from each of the 3 classes like this:

```
public static void Main (string [] args)
{
    Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
    Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1} are in {2}",
    teacher.namef1, teacher.Namet /*, UCourse string from the 1st class goes here*/);
}
```

So far that works to display the strings from the 2nd and 3rd classes, but how can I get the value of the `UCourse` string from the first class as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "call a string"?

Comment: Maybe you confuse "class" and "object" (i.e. "instance of a class")?

Comment: If you made `student` public (or exposed it at all) it becomes very trivial

Comment: Instead of returning a string value you can return entire object. example: 1. Student class could return a course object  instead course name; 2. Teacher class could return student object instead student name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your existing code and keep passing the strings through properties, then you almost solved it because your `Main()` method already shows the correct values of the strings from the 2nd and 3rd classes.

To access the `string` from the 1st class and use it in the 3rd class, you can add another property to the 3rd class to get it (same as you already did to get the `string` from the 2nd class).

For example:

```
class Teacher
{
    Student student = new Student();

    // Get the unique string from the 2nd class
    public string namef1
    {
        get { return student.Name; }
    }

    // Get the unique string from the 1st class that's already stored in the 2nd class
    public string UCourseName
    {
        get { return student.coursef1; }
    }

    // Set the string for the third class
    private string namet = "Sally";
    public string Namet
    {
        get { return namet; }
    }
}
```

And then you can update your `Main()` method to use it like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Teacher teacher = new Teacher();

    // Writes "Zach and Sally are in Computer Science"
    Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1} are in {2}", 
    teacher.namef1, teacher.Namet, teacher.UCourseName);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that would be :

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1} are in {2}",
        teacher.Namef1, teacher.Namet, teacher.Course);
    }

    private class UCourse
    {
        // Set the unique string for the 1st class
        private readonly string course = "Computer Scienece";
        public string Course { get { return this.course; } }
    }

    private class Student
    {
        // Set the unique string for the 2nd class
        private readonly string _name = "zach";
        public string Name { get { return this._name; } }

        // Get the string from the 1st class
        private readonly UCourse _ucourse = new UCourse( );
        public string Coursef1 { get { return this._ucourse.Course; } }
    }

    private class Teacher
    {           
        private readonly Student _student = new Student( );

        // Get the unique string from the 1nd class
        public string Course { get { return this._student.Coursef1; } }

        // Get the unique string from the 2nd class
        public string Namef1 { get { return this._student.Name; } }

        // Set the unique string for the 3rd class
        private readonly string _namet = "Sally";
        public string Namet { get { return this._namet; } }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you rethink your classes. Here is a small example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Example
{
    public class Course
    {
        public string CourseTitle { get; set; }

        public List<Student> Students { get; set; }

        public Course(string courseTitle)
        {
            CourseTitle = courseTitle;
            Students = new List<Student>();
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Student(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    public class Teacher
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }

        public Teacher(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            Courses = new List<Course>();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Teacher> teachers = new List<Teacher>();

            Course course1 = new Course("Astrophysics A");
            Course course2 = new Course("Coding C#");

            Student student1 = new Student("Peter");
            Student student2 = new Student("Bill");
            Student student3 = new Student("Anna");

            Teacher teacher1 = new Teacher("Mr. Williams");
            Teacher teacher2 = new Teacher("Mr. Jacobson");

            course1.Students.Add(student1);
            course1.Students.Add(student3);

            course2.Students.Add(student2);

            teacher1.Courses.Add(course1);
            teacher2.Courses.Add(course2);

            teachers.Add(teacher1);
            teachers.Add(teacher2);

            foreach (Teacher teacher in teachers)
            {
                foreach (Course course in teacher.Courses)
                {
                    foreach (Student student in course.Students)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1} are in {2}", student.Name, teacher.Name, course.CourseTitle);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I guess this way provides you more flexibility, in your code only 1 to 1 connections are possible.

Hope this was helpful.